# HCF of negative numbers

Tags: java, math

When I input two negative numbers in my program that finds the LCM and HCF of a number, the HCF returns 0. It works fine for positive numbers. Here is the code for HCF module. What can I do to fix it?

```
static int hcf(int x, int y){
    int hcf = 0;
    for (int i = x; i>=1; i--){
        if (y%i==0 && x%i==0){
            hcf = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return hcf;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is less or equal to 0, `i` will be initialized with `x` value and the `for` loop won't execute anything due to the condition `i >= 1`, thus the method will return 0.

Probably you should try to initialize `i` to `(int)Math.abs(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because your for loop only runs when i is greater than or equal to 1, due to `i>=1`, it won't run at all if i (or x) was less than 1 in the first place.

```
for (int i = x; i>=1; i--){ /*<<< here's your problem
         ^ you're setting i to a negative number, (if x is negative),
                 ^then only running if i is positive.
                  i is never positive, so the for loop
                  never runs. */
 //...
```

So, the problem is that the for loop won't start [i]at all[/i] if x is negative to begin with.

## **Solution!**

I cannot find an algorithm to calculate it other than [Euclid's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm), in Java it would look something like this:

```
static int hcf(int x, int y){
  return (y == 0) ? x : hcf (y, x%y);
}
```

In this function, recursion ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), [Java](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html)) is used, as well as [ternary assignment](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018).

If `y==0` then we return x, otherwise we return the hcf of y and the remainder when y is divided by x (that's the little % sign, it's the [modulo](http://www.javaranch.com/drive/modulo.html) operator). I recommend reading about it on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm).

Comment: I was curious to ask why recursive, but I realize I am learning functional programming in Java, so you are right it is neat, but it is hard to understand for novice people.

Comment: I think you should fix the op's issue and suggest that later

Comment: OK, I will try to make my answer a bit more meaningful :)